# Are quotes around $() unnecessary?

Tags: bash

I always thought I must put quotes around $() in bash, like in:

```
FOO="$(echo "bar    baz")"
```

but **apparently this is unnecessary**, at least **during *variable assignment***:

```
$ FOO=$(echo "foo       bar")
$ echo "$FOO"
foo       bar
```

On the other hand, if I just try to assign multiple words to a variable, I get an error, because it's interpreted as "set variable for duration of subsequent command":

```
$ FOO=bar     fooooo
fooooo: command not found
```

Also, if I just use $() without quotes **in *non-assignment* context**, they're again **treated as separate words**:

```
$ echo $(echo "baa    beee")
baa beee
```

So, **what are the rules regarding $() and "" interaction, and how safe is the non-quote variant?** I'd be especially grateful for manpage quotes, or some other authoritative references. Also, is there some "good practice/style" here?

Comment: Thanks for linking the duplicate! I couldn't find one by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, quotes are necessary to suppress otherwise normal behavior. In most contexts, you would need to quote the command substitution to suppress word-splitting and pathname expansion.

From the man page, under "Command substitution":

```
If the [command] substitution appears within double quotes, word 
splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results.
```

However, the right-hand side of an assignment is not one of those contexts. From the man page, under "PARAMETERS":

```
A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form

              name=[value]

If  value  is  not  given,  the  variable is assigned the null string.  All values
undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command  substitution,
arithmetic  expansion,  and quote  removal (see EXPANSION below).
```

Note that neither word splitting nor pathname expansion are mentioned.

As a rule, when in doubt, quote any expansion. The times when you *want* word-splitting and pathname expansion of an expansion are rare and usually obvious.